# For loop java - When int hit certain value, reset int back to 1

Tags: java

For a certain application I need the interger in For loop counter to reset back to 1 when it hit a value of 25.

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 35; i++)
```

How I can set a condition to set the counter back to 1 when it hit 25 ?

Comment: So your loop from 1 to 34 needs to reset to 0 when it hits 25.

Comment: I have to wonder why this is needed. I see something like that, I and I wonder if there is a flaw in the thinking.  I, and some other programmers, believe changing the value of the index within the block controlled by the for loop is a poor practice. In addition, in a case like this, it risks creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var j = 0; j < 34; ++j) {
    var i = 1 + (j % 25); // or 24
}
```

`%` is the modulo operator, remainder by integer division.

Depending whether you want 25 to be shown or not, adapt the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set i to 1 when i equals 25 in the loop body to reset the loop variable back to 1. Just be sure to do this *before* doing anything else, since it seems like you don't want to touch 25

```java
for ( var i = 1; i < 35; i++)
{
    if (i == 25)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    
    // Rest of the loop code
}
```

Comment: But if you really want to reset back to 1, why do you have conditioned it as `i < 35`? Plus this will make the loop infinite since you don't have any breaking condition

Comment: the above is just an example. I will not make it an infinite loop